# How to read links from rtf files and put them into csv via C#?

Tags: c#, csv, rtf

I'm looking for help with C#. I want to write a program that

1. reads hyperlinks from RTFs
2. puts those in CSV (or xls)

I'm such a beginner that even useful links, where should I get started, will be appreciated.

I've read some questions and answers related, but see no help in those.

Comment: Well, maybe get started at chosing your platform and Project type. Shall it be .Net Framework or .Net Core? Console-App? Service? WPF-App? WinForms App? Some kind of webservice? ...

Comment: .NET core it seems to be. Is that ok? -thanks

Comment: [reading a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time). [Regex for finding hyperlinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)

Comment: thanks, i'll look those

Comment: Open that RTF in a plain text editor to see what a link looks like in there. Then take small steps. Can you read the text (with codes) of one hardcoded RTF? Can you identify and select links? Can you write them to a CSV (also plain text)? Can you loop over the RTF files in some folder? Etc.